# POSIX ERE (extended regex) -- excluding a limited blacklist from a regex

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm trying to do a regex using posix to match some numbers of 5 digits:

```
551..
552..
553..

^(55[123]..)$
```

But i need to exclude the next numbers:

```
55341 55312 55227
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a regex that match some numbers and exclude another using posix (because my program is in C).

---

I'm currently compiling the regex with `REG_EXTENDED` and `REG_ICASE` flags:

```
status  = regcomp(&brb_regex->reg, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE);
```

...and executing it as follows:

```
status  = regexec(&brb_regex->reg, cmp_str, 10, brb_regex->match, 0);
```

Comment: Do you need to match all digit sequences as standalone strings but `55341`,  `55312` and `55227`? Or just 3-digit sequences, not 2- or 4+-digit sequences? Check [`(^|[^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]{3}($|[^[:digit:]])`](https://regex101.com/r/oH5fH8/1) (with `REG_EXTENDED` flag as I think you are using `<regex.h>`) to match only 3-digit sequences.

Comment: If you plan to match all digit sequences but the 3 mentioned, I'd rather use a regex with a capturing group: [`^55341|55312|55227|([0-9]{1,})$`](https://regex101.com/r/oH5fH8/2) and check the captured texts. If the capture group is empty, a wrong "number" was matched.

Comment: if you keep silent, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have read stribizhev's comment and deleted mine. Did not know that.

Comment: By the way -- there are two different POSIX regex languages, BRE and ERE; in the future, instead of just saying "POSIX regex", you should consider specifying which one explicitly.

Comment: (if you're using the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp()`, then your language is ERE; otherwise, it's BRE).

Comment: I need to match all digits in 551.. 552.. and 553..
Like
55112 55113 55114 55333 55222
But if the number was 
55341 55312 55227

Then the regex need to fail.

Sorry for the delay, i was working, and don't thing that the reply was so fast here

Comment: If you are using the answer provided by @Ziffusion, rather than editing the question to note this, click the checkbox next to that answer to flag it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do this using a logical expression of two regexes.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    regex_t r0, r1;
    regmatch_t rm[10];
    int s0, s1;

    s0 = regcomp(&r0, "^55[123]..$", REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE);
    s0 = regcomp(&r1, "^(55341)|(55312)|(55227)$", REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE);

    s0 = regexec(&r0, "55188", 10, rm, 0);
    s1 = regexec(&r1, "55188", 10, rm, 0);
    printf("===== %d %d match=%d\n", s0, s1, s0 == 0 && s1 != 0);

    s0 = regexec(&r0, "55341", 10, rm, 0);
    s1 = regexec(&r1, "55341", 10, rm, 0);
    printf("===== %d %d match=%d\n", s0, s1, s0 == 0 && s1 != 0);
}
```

You have a match when one regex matches and the other doesn't.

```
s0 == 0 && s1 != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way with POSIX regex is the hard way (you must list all possible cases):

```
^55(1[0-9][0-9]|2([013-9][0-9]|2[0-689])|3([0235-9][0-9]|1[013-9]|4[02-9]))$
```

*(or use `^55[132][0-9][0-9]$` and check forbidden numbers with a simple if)*

Comment: @stribizhev: lol, yes of course. (but it's possible to write a code to do it).

Comment: I ask because the [UtilityMill](http://utilitymill.com/edit/Regex_For_Range/) page is now inaccessible, but was public for a long time. I have just found [this Python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137-generate-a-regular-expression-to-match-an-arbitrar/), might be useful.

Comment: @stribizhev: I didn't know this page.

Comment: @stribizhev: note that the python code doesn't factorize branches and doesn't sort branches from the more probable to the less.

Comment: If you know of any other sources, please share. BTW, there are links to other solutions in the comments ([one more buggy version](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/numrangeregex/trunk/numrangeregex.py)).

Comment: I already have a field in my system that was a regex match, its like a route mark, so if the number was X, then the route is used, if the number isn't the route isn't used. Then, because of this, i need to match all numbers in 551.., but if the number was 55155 don't match, something like that.

The user can be wan't something like match all number 551.., but not 55155, 55166 and 55167

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2 steps approach instead of trying to solve with a single (posix-compatible) regex.

1. Filter out everything that matches your black list:

   `^(55341|55312|55227)$ # you can easily add new values`
2. Use a modified version of your regex to approve the remaining cases:

   `^55[1-3][0-9]{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

Use non consuming regex to find 5 digit numbers that start with 55[1,2,3] and then lookahed to check of number isn't one of blacklisted.

```
^(?=55[123]\d{2})((?!55(341|312|227))\d){5}$
```

P.S. Lookahed is not supported by all language

Comment: *Lookahed is not supported by all language* - exactly this is the case here. It does not even support `\d`, only `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: Like i said before, i'm using C in Unix (FreeBSD) This regex was invalid for me, thanks for the help